# Getting to the Model from within a Razor helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there a way to pass a view model to an @helper function?

I have a custom editor that displays Yes/No/Maybe radio buttons.  The code for this editor shown below.  Since it requires a custom function plus 3 lines of code to display each radio button, I'd like to encapsulate that code that creates each radio button and its associated label in a global @helper function, but I can't figure out how to move the RadioButtonFor into the global helper function.

Bob

This is the existing code:

```
@model System.String

@functions {
    // Returns an anonymous object that specifies the radio button HTML options
    private object HTMLOptions(string id, bool @checked) {
        if (@checked) {
            return new { id, @checked = "checked" };
        } else {
            return new { id };
        }
    }
}

@{
    string value = Model + "";
    string id;
}

<div class="option-list">
    @{id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("radioYes");}
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(q => q, "true", HTMLOptions(id, value == "true"))
    @Html.LabelFor(q => q, "Yes", new {@for = id})
    <br />

    @{id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("radioNo");}
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(q => q, "false", HTMLOptions(id, value == "false"))
    @Html.LabelFor(q => q, "No", new {@for = id})
    <br />

    @{id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("radioMaybe");}
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(q => q, "maybe", HTMLOptions(id, value == "maybe"))
    @Html.LabelFor(q => q, "Maybe", new {@for = id})
    <br />
</div>
```

I want to be able to write a general-purpose helper that encapsulates RadioButtonFor and LabelFor, plus my additional code to include the "checked" attribute, in one call, like this:

```
@model something

<div class="option-list">
    @MyRadioButtonAndLabelFor(q => something.x, "Yes",   "true") @* (model, label, value) *@
    @MyRadioButtonAndLabelFor(q => something.x, "No",    "false")
    @MyRadioButtonAndLabelFor(q => something.x, "Maybe", "maybe")
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Try like this:</strike>

```
@model System.String

@functions {
    private object HtmlAttributes(string id, string model, string value) {
        if (model == value) {
            return new { id, @checked = "checked" };
        }

        return new { id };
    }
}

@helper Radios(HtmlHelper<string> html) {
    var model = html.ViewData.Model;

    @html.RadioButtonFor(q => q, "true", HtmlAttributes("yes", model, "true"))
    @Html.LabelFor(q => q, "Yes", new { @for = "yes" })
    <br/>

    @html.RadioButtonFor(q => q, "false", HtmlAttributes("no", model, "false"))
    @Html.LabelFor(q => q, "No", new { @for = "no" })
    <br/>

    @html.RadioButtonFor(q => q, "maybe", HtmlAttributes("maybe", model, "maybe"))
    @Html.LabelFor(q => q, "Maybe", new { @for = "maybe" })
    <br/>
}

<div class="option-list">
    @Radios(Html)
</div>
```

---

UPDATE:

It seems that I have misread your question. After your update I understand better what you are trying to achieve. In order to achieve it you could write a custom Html helper:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyRadioButtonAndLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
        string label,
        object value
    )
    {
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var id = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(
            name + value
        );
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, value, new { id = id }));
        var labelTag = new TagBuilder("label");
        labelTag.SetInnerText(label);
        labelTag.Attributes["for"] = id;
        sb.Append(labelTag.ToString());
        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then you could have a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel
        {
            Value = "false"
        });
    }
}
```

and a corresponding view:

```
@model MyViewModel

<div class="option-list">
    @Html.MyRadioButtonAndLabelFor(q => q.Value, "Yes",   "true")
    @Html.MyRadioButtonAndLabelFor(q => q.Value, "No",    "false")
    @Html.MyRadioButtonAndLabelFor(q => q.Value, "Maybe", "maybe")
</div>
```

Remark: In order for the `MyRadioButtonAndLabelFor` custom extension method to be brought in scope you need to add the namespace in which its containing class (`HtmlExtensions`) has been declared either in the namespaces tag in your `~/Views/web.config` (not `~/web.config`) or within the view itself by adding a `@using ...` directive.

---

You could also define the helper inline inside your Razor view if you prefer:

```
@functions {
    public IHtmlString MyRadioButtonAndLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(
        HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
        string label,
        object value
    )
    {
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var id = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(name + value);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, value, new { id = id }));
        var labelTag = new TagBuilder("label");
        labelTag.SetInnerText(label);
        labelTag.Attributes["for"] = id;
        sb.Append(labelTag.ToString());

        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
<div class="option-list">
    @MyRadioButtonAndLabelFor(Html, q => q.Value, "Yes",   "true")
    @MyRadioButtonAndLabelFor(Html, q => q.Value, "No",    "false")
    @MyRadioButtonAndLabelFor(Html, q => q.Value, "Maybe", "maybe")
</div>
```

As far as Razor helpers are concerned (`@helper` definition), well, they cannot be generic, therefore you will have troubles declaring such a construct.

Comment: Thanks Darin.  I guess my question wasn't crystal clear.  I've updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: @Bob.at.SBS, after your update it is much more clear what you are after. I have updated my answer with an example of how you could achieve this.